# Converting integers to alphabetic characters

Tags: c++, ascii

I want to assign grades based on the test scores.

- **A** for *90-100*.
- **B** for *80-89*.
- **C** for *70-79*.
- **D** for *60-69*.
- **F** for *0-59*.

I know if you use `switch` or `if..else` statements, there will be no more than 5 statements but anyone has any better solution?

I used ASCII values to go about it but in terms of lines of code it's merely the same.

Here is the code:

```
Score/=10;
Score=min(9,Score);
Score=9-Score;
Score+=65;
if(Score<=68)
{
  cout<<static_cast<char>(Score)<<endl;
}
else
{
   cout<<"F"<<endl;
}
```

Comment: A series of if statements would be far more readable than what you have now. What is your interest in making the code *shorter*?

Comment: `65` better written as `'A'`.

Comment: How come the value of Score keeps changing?

Comment: @TomBlodget should I explain the code or you're asking me how do I take different values in the variable Score?

Comment: It's just a comment from an ontological and readability perspective. You could say I'm a "const by default" guy. In the first line, you are calculating the decade of the score.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A standard approach in situations when the number of input choices is limited is to use a look-up table:

```
cout << "FFFFFFDCBAA"[Score/10];
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/e5uSsE)

> (from comments) could you please explain what's going on in the code?

String literal `"FFFFFFDCBAA"` is treated as a `const char*` pointer, which allows application of indexer `[]` operator. `Score` is divided by ten in integers, producing a number between 0 and 10, inclusive. Eleven characters in the string correspond to letter grades of "raw" score divided by ten.

Comment: my head is like pls no, but my heart is loving this :/

Comment: It works great until you decide to adopt +/- grading :-)

Comment: a string is an array of chars therefore you can access them

Comment: @CodyGray That's true - for "+/-" grading you'd need a bigger look-up table, and it will be a table of strings.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, could you please explain what's going on in the code? It seems beautiful. Any links perhaps. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: This is not a "standard approach". It's cute and brittle, and would never pass any sort of code review. Use `if` statements instead.

Comment: @isanae This approach does not come close to anything that could be reasonably described as "cute". Once the initial confusion caused by unfamiliarity is gone, lookup tables become very readable. If someone on your team gives you hard time about code like this, consider finding yourself a different team :-)

Answer (score 0):

Code length is a bad criteria =) I suggest you to use custom mapping functions (integer to char or string) or class with `switch / if` for many reasons.

If we will follow the OOP approach we can define a class `Grade` with constructor from integer `Grade(int)` with method `toString()` or `toChar`. It's better to incapsulate grade transformation logic inside class from client code - because in the future you can add different locales (for example we in Russia have no A-C grade system, we just have 1-5) - and load locale from config, for example in `XML`. Also you can predefine ranges statically in some container and run for-each to assign char representation, but its unefficient in terms of time and memory.

I think it's better solution write code for humans (except for such cases when performance or other criteria are important - but as far as I can see, it's not the case)

Comment: I don't find it reasonable to write a class for a task as simple as this one.

Comment: projects grows =)  dasblinkenlight solution takes human time to understand and change (if). class incapsulate it. switch make it clean.